# Creating a lib from other libs : is it possible?

Tags: c++, windows-ce, platform-builder

I'm using Windows CE Platform Builder and my code is written in C++ . For each of the folders in the project I'm creating a lib ( the code is statically linked ) . However , there are about 20 libs so far . Is there a way to reduce their number ? I was thinking of creating a lib from other libs , but I don't know if that's even possible . Is it ?

**EDIT:** how could I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried it in a while, but traditionally you could use the librarian tool (LIB.EXE) to do this sort of thing.

```
$ lib /?
Microsoft (R) Library Manager Version 8.00.50727.762
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

usage: LIB [options] [files]

   options:

      /DEF[:filename]
      /ERRORREPORT:{NONE|PROMPT|QUEUE|SEND}
      /EXPORT:symbol
      /EXTRACT:membername
      /INCLUDE:symbol
      /LIBPATH:dir
      /LIST[:filename]
      /LTCG
      /MACHINE:{ARM|EBC|IA64|MIPS|MIPS16|MIPSFPU|MIPSFPU16|
                SH4|THUMB|X64|X86}
      /NAME:filename
      /NODEFAULTLIB[:library]
      /NOLOGO
      /OUT:filename
      /REMOVE:membername
      /SUBSYSTEM:{BOOT_APPLICATION|CONSOLE|EFI_APPLICATION|
                  EFI_BOOT_SERVICE_DRIVER|EFI_ROM|EFI_RUNTIME_DRIVER|
                  NATIVE|POSIX|WINDOWS|WINDOWSCE}[,#[.##]]
      /VERBOSE
      /WX[:NO]
```

Normally the librarian takes .OBJ files and combines them into a .LIB, but I think it will also read .LIB files as input.

Answer (score 1):

as mentionet above, lib.exe can really merge a couple of lib files into one library, just put lib files into command line instead of obj files. few seconds ago i've tried it with a fortran lib and a c lib - everything works perfect